# Injecting agent properties into HTTP headers

Tags: iis, openam

I have an SSO setup using OpenAM 13.5 protecting an application on IIS with an IIS Web Agent.

The application receives user/session attributes by mapping the appropriate properties in the Agent configuration - everything is working fine, however I'd like to take things a step further: I'd like to pass the application a few agent properties as HTTP headers - i.e.:

- CUSTOM-LOGIN-URL = com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url
- CUSTOM-EDITPASSWORD-URL = (set by a custom agent property)
- CUSTOM-EDITPROFILE-URL = (set by a custom agent property)
- CUSTOM-LOGOUT-URL = com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url
- CUSTOM-GOTO-PARAMETER-NAME = com.sun.identity.agents.config.redirect.param

This way I could avoid hardwiring the application to the specific SSO config details.

Do you have any idea on how I could achieve that, possibly without writing code?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible OOTB. It might be possible by implementing https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/apidocs/com/sun/identity/entitlement/ResourceAttribute.html

Please see https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/dev-guide/#sec-policy-spi